# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined in chained prototype function

Tags: javascript

I'm currently developing a small validation script at http://mandala.morgana-design.com/contacto and am facing a few log errors through the chrome inspect tool.

It is not recognizing the parameter `input` in the prototype chain function. Despite the form functioning as it should, I still would like to correct these errors. Any advice is appreciated.

```
main.js?1499689891:178 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
    at Validation.bindEvents (main.js?1499689891:178)
    at Validation.init (main.js?1499689891:133)
    at new Validation (main.js?1499689891:121)
    at main.js?1499689891:264
    at main.js?1499689891:269
```

Part of the code that receives the errors :

```
    (function(window, document, undefined) {"use strict";
        Validation.prototype.bindEvents = function(input, button) {
        var required = this.options.required, valid = this.options.valid, invalid = this.options.invalid;

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            this.validate();
        }.bind(this));

        input.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
            if(input.classList.contains(invalid) || input.classList.contains(valid)){this.inspect(input);}
            if(!input.classList.contains(required) && this.trim(input.value) === ""){
                input.className = "";
            }
        }.bind(this));

        input.addEventListener('blur', function(){
            if(this.trim(input.value) !== "" || input.classList.contains(required)){this.inspect(input);}
        }.bind(this));
        input.addEventListener('focus', function(){
                button.className = "";
        }.bind(this));


        if(input.type === "radio" && input.name === "radio_destination"){
            var field = document.getElementById("destination");

            input.addEventListener('click',function(){
                if(input.checked && input.id === "yes"){
                    this.radioButton(input);
                }else{
                    field.value = "";
                    field.className = "";
                }
            }.bind(this));

            if(input.checked) {
                if(input.id === "yes") {
                    field.className = required;
                }else {
                    field.value = "";
                    field.className = "";
                }
            }


    }

    if(this.trim(input.value) !== "" ) {this.inspect(input);}};
})(window, document);
```

Apologies if this post is not transparent enough, I don't use stackoverflow that often.

Thanks in advance

Comment: post a working snippet

Comment: Is `input` `undefined` by any chance?

Comment: Means that input is undefined... How do you call bindEvents?

Comment: @Kinduser and not all browsers support it so if you do not have a build that fixes it, you can't use them.

Comment: The input is undefined, but is being used as a parameter, I can post a snippet. @Kind user sorry, I'm just a newbie

Comment: @epascarello IE doesn't support it, agreed. But who cares about IE? It's a dead browser, mainly used to download Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @Kinduser funny....

Comment: Just use arrow function everywhere, https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I dont support IE <11 for this website.

Comment: @Kind user, thanks, I'll check it

Comment: Found the problem thanks to @epascarello! You were right, input wasn't defined correctly! @Kind user, the arrow function did not solve my problem, but I did learn something new that I will apply in my future development, thank you!